# Android horizontal progress bar not working while downloading an image

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to download an image while using a horizontal progress bar then storing it in a file in my SD card, the code is the following :

```
  package com.erc.library;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class Splashscreen extends Activity {

    ProgressBar pd;
    String a="";
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);

        pd=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        pd.setMax(100);




        new ProgressTask().execute();
    }


    private class ProgressTask extends AsyncTask <String,String,String>
    {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {

             pd.setIndeterminate(false);
             pd.setMax(100);
             Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),a,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {

             pd.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
        }


        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) 
        {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"done",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
             try
                {
                    URL url = new URL("http://mylink/myimage.png");

                    URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();
//                  ucon.setReadTimeout(15000);
//                  ucon.setConnectTimeout(30000);

                    InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
                    int lenghtOfFile = ucon.getContentLength();
                    BufferedInputStream inStream = new BufferedInputStream(is, 1024 * 5);

                    String baseDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/library";
                    String fileName = "test.png";

                    // Not sure if the / is on the path or not
                    File file = new File(baseDir + File.separator + fileName);



                //    File file = new File(this.getDir(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Sayegh library", Context.MODE_PRIVATE) + "/yourfile.png");

                    if (file.exists())
                    {
                        file.delete();
                    }
                    file.createNewFile();

                    FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    byte[] buff = new byte[5 * 1024];

                    int len;
                    byte data[] = new byte[1024];
                       long total = 0;
                    while ((len = inStream.read(buff)) != -1)
                    {
                        total += len;
                          // publishing the progress....
                          // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
                     //  pd.setProgress((int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile));
                      //    publishProgress("" + (int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile));
                        outStream.write(buff, 0, len);
                    }

                    outStream.flush();
                    outStream.close();
                    inStream.close();

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                a=e.toString(); 

                }

            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



            return null;

        }


    }

}
```

Well the progress bar is not showing any progress and the image isn't being downloaded, any help please ?

Comment: from where did you call ProgressTask

Comment: Your code have some problems. 1, you called `Toask.makeText(...).show()` inside a background job. 2, Why you convert `int` to `String` at `publishProgress("" + (int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile))` then  convert it back at `pd.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));`

Comment: I edited the code guys, it's  still not working

Comment: @MonzerYaghi nope, that is my comment for your code, not my answer for your question. I think you should visit http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html to get more informations about `AsyncTask`

Comment: @MonzerYaghi onPreExecute() and onPostExecute() are executed on the UI thread you can all Toask.makeText(...).show() here, it's nothing wrong. Only doInBackground() method is executed inside background thread.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to set permissions.
If it does not help, please read the `adb logcat` output and post the relevant part here.

Comment: Those are the permissions that I have in my androidmanifest.xml :

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: please make sure that the `uses-permission` entries are children of `manifest` rather than something else (it __must not__ be `application` or `activity`)